# How to tell what changed in Compatibility Mode in IE

Tags: php, .htaccess, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way to determine what is being changed in compatibility mode in IE?

I have a drop down menu (mega menu built into OpenCart) that renders properly in IE 8 on a XP version of Windows.  But in Windows 8 with IE 10 it only renders correctly in IE 10 compatibility mode.

I've tried several methods to force X-UA-Compatible including:

.htaccess: `Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=EmulateIE7"`

PHP: `header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7');`

Document Head: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >`

But in looking at Developer Tools in IE 10 under the script tab IE is still sending the first entry after the  tag as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" ""><HTML lang="en"><HEAD><META content="IE=10.000" 
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
```

So clearly there's no means (at least not that I can find) to force compatibility in IE 10.

Is there a way to figure out what changes are made to the document in compatibility mode so that I can manually correct them in my JS and CSS?  Obviously that's the best solution anyway, but I have no idea how to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `IE=EmulateIE7`, use `IE=edge` - this has the additional benefit of removing that Compatibility Biew button from next to the Reload button, which is great because that button is really annoying when I'm using the mouse and go to click the Reload button and end up clicking the Compatibility View button instead, and [rant redacted]

Anyway, yeah, using `IE=edge` will make it so that the only way to get into Compatibility Mode is to specifically go into the Developer Tools and change modes there - and if people are doing that, then they don't deserve the time it would take you to fix their problem.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference what I use, it doesn't work. IE still forces IE=10.000 in the header.